# Device Name from bluetooth address

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to get a device's name by only having the bluetooth address even if it is not paired with the device. I only took note of the Bluetooth address with my Samsung phone but the device was never paired with the samsung phone so I only have the bluetooth address and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: how is it possible

Comment: HCI Remote_Name_Request command does exactly what you need.

Comment: How do you use the command ?

Comment: Refer to Bluetooth Core specification to find all the details. Of course, if you provided your OS details (or hardware) the answer could be more specific. But for now this is a spherical horse in the vacuum (absolutely stupid) questions

Comment: Has the device only ever been "nearby" or have you actually connected and paired with it? Please state your operating system and if possible what version of it you are using. What bluetooth hardware and software is your computer using? Where do you expect this information to be kept? Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1468070/edit) to clarify. Do not use comments to clarify details that should be in your question as they will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the device name from the device address using the [BluetoothView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_viewer.html) software.

Comment: I have downloaded the software but how do you type the address, I can't find any way

Comment: You should see all the Bluetooth devices in the vicinity with their name and address.

Comment: I know but there are No nearby devices, what I want is to type the address and then get the name

Comment: If it is not near, it can't be done as far as I know.